# can't connect to home network with 14.04

Tags: wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu14.04 on my old laptop in order to try a Linux OS for surfing the net. However I can't work out how to get connected to my home network wirelessly. I know nothing of the OS, or of computer programming. Is there anyone out there who can guide me (in English words of very few syllables) how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Very few letters: read the end user manual [chapter on WiFi](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless.html).

;-)